# How to implement pagination in cassandra for API?

Tags: java, cassandra, pagination, datastax, query-builder

I want to implement paging in cassandra using QueryBuilder (datastax). For example /api/5 will fetch the 5th page of results with limit 20. As far as I have read, we need to store the last page state. Is it possible to directly access a particular page. Basically, what is the cassandra equivalent for limit x, offset y?

Main concern here is performance (time based).

Answer (score 2):

All queries are paged by the driver already you are correct.

- You can define the size of your page with the following parameter in `application.conf` or in the statement.

```
datastax-java-driver.basic.request.page-size = 5000
```

- In the `ResultSet` returned object you can invoke `getAvailableWithoutFetching` to know how much records you have in this page. The records are stored in a `Iterable` and when you reach the end of the page the driver will fetch for you next page under the hood. Driver Documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/core/paging/
- You might have heard about the `PagingState` which is a parameter you can store and use to reemit in a second call with exact same query to access directly page X - but **this not what you want here.**

To go with the limit/offset I would simply iterate on the records in the `ResultSet` like here :

```java
public Stream<Stock> findAllBySymbol(
      @NonNull String symbol,
      @NonNull Instant start,
      @NonNull Instant end,
      long offset,
      long limit) {
    BoundStatement bound = findBySymbol.bind(symbol, start, end);
    ResultSet rs = session.execute(bound);
    Stream<Row> stream = Stream.iterate(rs.one(), Objects::nonNull, row -> rs.one());
    return stream.skip(offset).limit(limit).map(rowMapper);
  }
```

Source. You may notice that in the repo you have samples for reactive and asynchronous as well : https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-reactive-demo/blob/master/1_sync/src/main/java/com/datastax/demo/sync/repository/SyncStockRepository.java#L119

Comment: Thanks. What I am concerned about is the response time. If i access row n to m, will it be equivalent to iterating over the m rows unlike a SQL table?